# Use outside variables inside a TypeScript function.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, chart.js

I have this variable:

```
public originalData: Array<any> = [];
```

and this function:

```
canvas.onclick = function (evt) {
            console.log(this.originalData);
}
```

The function is unable to see this.originalData - how do I go about accessing that and other variable properly within my 'onclick' method? I now I can do this outside of the function:

```
var dataCopy = this.originalData;
```

and access it via 'dataCopy', but is there a way to access the variable **without** creating a new var variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best way is to use [the ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the this value (does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target).

For your application it looks like this:

```
canvas.onclick = (evt) => {
     console.log(this.originalData); 
};
```

Or even:

```
canvas.onclick = e => console.log(this.originalData);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky in JavaScript. The this in your function points to the function. Since you are using typescript you probably have a class to wrap the variable and the function. You can try `ClassName.originalData`